# Can I use mach to do unit test for thunderbird on windows?

Tags: unit-testing, thunderbird

I've been doing some thunderbird develop lately, and wanna do some unit test for my XPCOM module. I notice that there is a tool called mach in mozilla which can automatically run a set of test cases at one time, but when I run "mach help" on windows, It shows that 
"is_platform_supported - Must have a Firefox, Android or B2G build."

Since I'm using thunderbird, does that mean that I can't use mach for unit test for thunderbird? If not so - which I hope - how can I change my config to use that tool?

Any reples from you will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, mozilla/mach xpcshell-test does not work (see Bug [934170](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934170)). As a workaround, use the following:

- First, switch to the object directory after building Thunderbird.
- To run all xpcshell tests, use: `make xpcshell-tests`
- To run a single xpcshell test, use (e.g.): `make xpcshell-tests TEST_PATH=mailnews/news/test/unit/test_server.js`
- To run all xpcshell tests in a given directory, use (e.g.): `make xpcshell-tests TEST_PATH=mailnews/news`